# How to write numerals of equations by the digits of a non-Latin-based language?

Tags: polyglossia, mathspec, persian

I am typesetting a document in Persian using `polyglossia`. Thanks to `fontspec` under XeLaTeX, I can copy/paste Persian digits in the text, but when I do the same for equations, compilation render nothing for the pasted Persian digit. I tried to use `mathspec`, say, `\setmathsfont(Digits){XB Niloofar}`, but it changed nothing.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathspec}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=eastern]{persian}
\newfontfamily\persianfont[Script=Arabic]{XB Niloofar}

\setmathsfont(Digits){XB Niloofar}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation}
        E = mc^۲
    \end{equation}      
\end{document}
```

`\localnumeral{2}` and `\farsidigits{2}` also did nothing in the math mode.

How can I get that `۲` (the equivalent of 2 in Persian digits) in an equation like the one above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In LuaLaTeX, you can use the (deprecated) `Numbers=Arabic` option.  This will give you spurious warnings about the font not having that feature, but it is in fact implemented through `luaotfload` and will work.

Since XeTeX does not support it, and `mathspec` requires XeTeX, here I switch to `unicode-math` and free fonts distributed with TeX:

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase,
                      Ligatures=TeX,
                      Renderer=HarfBuzz }

\setdefaultlanguage{persian}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}[Scale=1.0]
\setsansfont{Libertinus Sans}
\setmonofont{Libertinus Mono}
\newfontfamily\persianfont{Amiri}[
  Language=Farsi,
  Script=Arabic,
  Numbers=Arabic ]
% Define \persianfontsf here, if needed
\setfontfamily\persianfonttt{ALM Fixed}[
  Language=Farsi,
  Script=Arabic,
  Numbers=Arabic ]
\setmathfont{Libertinus Math}
\setmathfont{Amiri-Regular}[
  range=up/num,
  Language=Farsi,
  Script=Arabic,
  Numbers=Arabic ]
\setmathfont{Amiri-Bold}[
  range=bfup/num,
  Language=Farsi,
  Script=Arabic,
  Numbers=Arabic ]

\newunicodechar{۱}{1}
\newunicodechar{۲}{2}
% Etc.

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        E &= m\symup{c}^2 \\
        E &= m\symup{c}^۲
    \end{align}      
\end{document}
```

[image: Amiri/Libertinus Math sample]

You would need to use a more complex definition of `\newunicodechar{۱}`, etc., in a multi-lingual document.  (Something like, `\newunicodechar{۲}{\ifmmode\mathalpha{\textnormal{\textpersian{۲}}}\else\textpersian{۲}\fi}`)  If you want a different form of the digits, use another font, or a stylistic set.

If you want to stick with XeLaTeX, you could try `Mapping=farsidigits` instead of `Numbers=Arabic`.  If you want to use math symbols from a legacy font, but letters and digits from an OpenType font, you can replace `mathspec` with `mathfont`, which works in LuaLaTeX..

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `\text{\localnumeral{<digit>}}` is one way to go. So,

```
\begin{equation}
    E = mc^{\text{\localnumeral{2}}}
\end{equation}
```

yields

[image]

Comment: Note that you probably want `\textnormal`. The `\text` command inherits the formatting of the surrounding text, so `\text{2}` would be italicized within a theorem statement! You might, however, want to use bold math alongside bold text. In that case, use `\textup`, to set the digits upright but match the current font weight.

Comment: I also had an answer of my own.

Comment: Finally, you probably would want to set `۱`, `۲`, etc. active with `\newunicodechar`, something like `\newunicodechar{۲}{\ifmmode\mathalpha{\textnormal{\textpersian{۲}}}\else\textpersian{۲}\fi}`.  You could then type ۲ in either text or math mode and have it just work.